# Merge Branch to Master - 2 ways?

Tags: git

Let's say I have 2 branches:

- master
- issue1

Once `issue1` completes, I can merge it into `master` with 2 ways:

1. pull from `master` into `issue1`

   git checkout issue1
   git pull origin master
   pull request of issue1 into master
2. merge `issue1` into `master`

   git checkout master
   git merge issue1
   pull request of `master` into `master`

Looking at the Git book's tutorial on [merges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), I think that #2 is standard.

Does it matter which approach I take to merge `issue1` into `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it matters.

"Pulling" master into issue1 leaves master unchanged, requiring your pull request, which will generate a series of redundant merge commits. You're literally merging master into issue1, and then merging issue1 into master, but by using a pull request for the second merge you're insuring that at least one merge commit is created, even if it's not required.

If you want to update master to include issue1, the easiest way is to merge issue1 into master, or simply directly issue a pull request to perform the same merge. One step, and it provides the same outcome as the the first process, with the potential to skip the generation of a redundant merge commit.

Either option still merges issue1 into master, but your first method generates an ugly commit history with redundant merges, for no reason. Hardly ideal.

"#2" is definitely standard.